# Why users have no value whatsoever?

Tags: discussion, support

I've been using this website for quite some time, and was helped many times, I think I was able to help people too, at least I tried. This place is great, fast answers, quality content, but it lacks the basic: human warmth.

Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512653/how-can-w3c-errors-influence-in-seo

I know I made errors, but I'm not perfect, how can I tell which category should I post at, if it is automatically chosen? How can my question be the same as the one from other people, if every question have different answers?

I was even rebuked in some questions, where they edited my topics with stuff like "I'm aware that I posted in the wrong place...", I was ashamed when I read that. Is that a way to treat people who are collaborating for the good of the site?

There is another point, even when I posted questions in the right places, using the right things, there was always some one to downrate the topics.

I sincerely don't know what's going on around here.

Why do you treat users so bad? Why do you feel like you have the duty of teaching them a lesson or two?

Put yourselves in our place, would you be happy if your website were considered the worst one on a tv/youtube channel about websites reviews?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking here. The question you link has a single downvote. Were there previous negative commments on it?

Comment: Also, that question seems broad, as different search engines will probably care more/less than others assuming they even tell you

Comment: On other downvoted questions [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939106/njq8ishere-vbs-how-to-remove-this-virus-manually) isn't actually a question but instructions on how to remove a virus. Which is off topic for two reasons

Comment: *"how can I tell which category should I post at, if it is automatically chosen?"* ... what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't ask questions that are off topic and you will not get a bad reception. Read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) articles about what is and is not on-topic and those about how to ask questions - follow those and you will not go wrong.

Comment: And I'm sorry, but going through your various questions, I don't get the idea you know yet what is on-topic for the site, nor what a good question is. That would absolutely need work. It's nothing personal, it's not us being cold, but downvotes and close votes happen on content that's not all that good or doesn't belong.

Comment: *"Why do you feel like you have the duty of teaching them a lesson or two?"* - because otherwise this website would be flooded with crap and turn into a second YahooAnswers or ExpertSexChange.

Comment: Do you call yourself a new user? Your profile claims you have been a member for over 2 years. Hardly new.

Comment: I looked at all 11 of your questions, and no one has ever edited anything like "I'm aware that I posted in the wrong place..." into your questions. [Someone did *remove it* once](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18936601/revisions), because that kind of commentary doesn't belong in a question. If you're not sure where to post a question, please check the Help center or ask on Meta.

Comment: *"Put yourselves in our place"* -- who are you referring to with "our"? (I am just a user like you, and I don't feel treated this way.)

Comment: Stack Exchange sites actually try pretty had not to assign a "value" (good or bad) to users; the rule of thumb is "judge the content, not the poster". Now it is true that certain very prominent users get a good (human) reputation as well as a good (site) reputation, but if you don't show up in front of others daily, then they mostly don't know who you are. Which means that you can safely assume they are judging your content, not your character. Want a better response? Improve your content.

Answer (score 14):

## Downvoted Questions

Your three downvoted questions have only a single downvote a piece, which isn't huge. Regardless I have tried to review each one to identify any problems

#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939106/njq8ishere-vbs-how-to-remove-this-virus-manually

This is not actually a question, this is a set of instructions on how to remove a virus.

1. Stack Exchange sites are for questions (which you can self answer if you like), not for free form posts
2. This is off topic for Stack Overflow, which is about programming problems

#### [How to prevent whole page and source code from loading if javascript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170265/how-to-prevent-whole-page-and-source-code-from-loading-if-javascript-is-disabled)

I'm less sure exactly what's wrong with this, however starting with "Well, this probably was asked before" is not getting off to a great start as it pretty much says "I've not bothered to look"

#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512653/how-can-w3c-errors-influence-in-seo

This question seems broad, as different search engines will probably care more/less than others assuming they even tell you. Stack Overflow questions are best when they have a single definitive answer.

## Non downvoted (but still questionable) questions

#### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936601/looking-for-php-script-that-allow-users-to-create-their-own-website

This question appears to be a request for a recommendation, these questions [are stated as being off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There is even a specific close reason for them :

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
> off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
> attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
> and what has been done so far to solve it.

## Deleted questions

As pointed out by Oded♦ you currently have deleted questions, these also count towards a question ban. If possible, improve these so they are on topic and request (by flag) that they be undeleted. However, if they are like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939106/njq8ishere-vbs-how-to-remove-this-virus-manually it is likely they are terminally off topic and not salvageable; if this is the case try to improve your existing questions as improvements to these may lift you out of the ban.

Comment: To complete the picture - there are a few deleted questions (some with downvotes) and the op has fallen into the question ban.

Comment: --- My answer is too big, so I posted it on an external website ---
http://copytaste.com/n7195

Comment: @Mathew I don't think you have offended people.  I think people were unsure exactly what this question was about. Sometimes it can be hard to determine exactly what is off topic. Especially what is "too broad". I hope I've helped at least somewhat in that

Comment: I also think so, I didn't make a very clear feedback, I'm not a native speaker of English, so I try to do my best when I'm writing, unfortunately, sometimes I can't express myself as I expect.
You helped me for sure, you and the other people who answered. I'm glad for have had this conversation. Also, reading what was written by everyone made me realize a few things too, resulting in a self improvement.

Comment: @023023 The link to your answer is broken, won't you fix it?

Comment: @mindstormsboi it looks like some of the answers were deleted